# How to use diagram to explain Conditional Probability?

Tags: probability

There are three identical wallets $A$, $B$, $C$. Two of them are empty and one contains a banknote.

When you pick wallet $A$, the probability that $A$ contains the banknote is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Now you open wallet $C$ and realize that the there is no banknote inside $C$.

What is the probability that $A$ contains the banknote now? Should you change your decision?

How can we solve this problem in the most easy-to-understand without using Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: What do you think the answer is, and why?

Comment: I suppose H: "A contains banknote", E: "C doesn't contain banknote. P(H)=1/3, P(E)=2/3. P(E/H)=1 so P(H/E)=1/2. I am quite doubt about this answer so I would like to ask

Comment: Isn't this essentially equivalent to the Monty Hall problem? If so, you should change your decision to wallet B (there was a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of the banknote being in B or C when you started and now you know for sure it is not C).

Comment: Thank you so much Alex Riley. Your key word really helps!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you know $C$ is empty, you should choose wallet $B$ instead.

The reason is that you originally picked wallet $A$, but there was a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of the banknote not being there (it could have been in either of $B$ or $C$ with an equal probability of $\frac{1}{3}$).

But you subsequently learn that $C$ is empty! The probability that your original guess is correct is still $\frac{1}{3}$ and the probability that your original guess is incorrect is still $\frac{2}{3}$. But this now means that the banknote is in $B$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Without Bayes, the answer follows from the definition of conditional probability; using your notation$$P(H|E)=\frac{P(H\cap E)}{P(E)}=\frac{P(H)}{P(E)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Initially there were 3 wallets ,so the sample space was  S= {A, B, C} , with $\\P(A) = P(B) = P(C)= {1\over 3 }$,
Now that you have opened wallet C  and found there was no banknote , your "knowledge" changes , and so does the sample space.
The new sample space thus becomes S={A,B}
With $P(A)=P(B)={1\over 2} $

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the (very famous) Monty Hall problem, which is usually stated as follows:

> On a game show, a contestant is presented with three doors.  Hidden behind one of those doors is a great prize, such as a car.  Behind the other two doors are hidden booby prizes, such as goats.  The contestant selects a door to open (say, Door 1), but before the door is opened, the host (Monty Hall) opens one of the *other* doors (say, Door 2) to reveal a goat.  Is it to the advantage of the contestant to switch doors?

Suppose that the contestant chooses Door 1, and we want to know the probability of the contestant winning if they *switch* doors.  In this case, we can cook up the following tree diagram to help understand the situation:

[image: Diagram of one part of the Monty Hall problem]

To determine the probability of an event, we can multiply probabilities along a branch (this essentially follows from the identity
$$ P(A \land B) = P(A) \cdot P(B \mid A); $$
the branches give conditional probabilities).  Thus, for example, given that the contestant chose Door 1, the probability that the car is behind Door 1 *and* the host reveals the goat behind Door 2 is
$$ \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}. $$
Since we are assuming that the contestant switches whenever given the opportunity, this represents a loss for the contestant (the car was behind Door 1, but the contestant switches to Door 3).  The remaining branches of the diagram are handled similarly.

Since all of the events are mutually exclusive, we can add the probabilities, thus the probability of the contestant winning is the sum of the probabilities associated to the two bottom branches, i.e.
$$ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}. $$
Thus if the contestant chooses Door 1 then switches, they will win a car with probability $\frac{2}{3}$.  The other two scenarios (the contestant choosing Door 2 or Door 3 to start) are similar.

To answer your question, change the word "Door" to "Wallet" and "Car" to "Banknote."  You can leave the goats.